# cgimagecreatewithmaskingcolors changes all the transparent region to black

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I am using `CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors()` to remove particular color from the `UIImage`. The color removal process works fine but the transparent region in the image turns black after masking process.See the code pasted below.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = self.editedImage.CGImage;
CGImageRef myColorMaskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(imageRef, myMaskingColors);

UIImage *newImage = [self normalizeWithAlpha:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:myColorMaskedImage]];
CGImageRelease(myColorMaskedImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a second masking pass to mask the black:

```
    float colorMaskingLow[6] = {0, low, 0, low, 0, low};
    float colorMaskingHigh[6] = {high, 255, high, 255, high, 255};

    UIImage *image = [self maskColors:colorMaskingHigh inImage:image];
    return [self maskColors:colorMaskingLow inImage:image];
```

(where the `maskColors:inImage:` function is what you specify above)